# Is it ok to disable the next button until all of the required fields on a wizard form have been completed?

Tags: forms, buttons, wizard, disable

I'm considering disabling the next and done buttons on my wizard until all of the required fields on the corresponding step have been completed.

My first thought is that if something shouldn't be clicked then disable it until it can be. However, I'm realising there may be an issue with doing that in this scenario, the main one being that the user may not know what to do in order to get the next button enabled.

What is best practice in this scenario?